# How to set up "The Grinder" agent to recognize the console?

Tags: grinder

I really want to start working with "The Grinder" but unfortunately my agent doesn't find the console what ever I try.
The message issued by the agent is "(agent): Failed to connect to 'localhost/127.0.0.1:6372', proceeding without the console; set grinder.useConsole=false to disable this warning."

- Both console and agent are located on local-host.
- It happens both when I start the agent without a grinder.properties file at all and when I do use grinder.properties file with a default grinder.consoleHost property.
- It happens even when I set grinder.consoleHost to be my IP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Well, stupid as it may sound, don't set the Console Host property in the console itself. To set this property open the console -> File -> Options -> Communication tab. Leave the Console Host empty otherwise the agent won't connect to the console (have no idea why, I thought setting it to be my IP was a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

If you set the console host in the console, you'll also need to set the same value in the grinder.consoleHost key in the grinder.properties file used by the Agents.